# Trying to use MAP, Lambda, & XMatch but unable to get the desired result

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

[Sample Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1q9Jco4RXpSqmxyezycUHwsmq7c5eRra5swRnzOILQlQ/edit#gid=1243178168)

I was introduced to MAP function via the answer to another, similar, question I asked a few days back. Another user solved that problem and provided me with the formula I needed. After watching some tutorials, I am trying to adjust the formula for a similar use-case; however, I keep breaking the formula.

Here is a sample from the main sheet:
[image: Pizza Tab w/ notes in ColG to help clarify]

When i took the screen shot i included some notes - but the value returned should be 1440 - which corresponds to 4 (F2) * 360 (the value pulled in from the other sheets that equates to a 10x8 Sicilian.

The formula sits in the Pizza tab cell G2. It is as follows:

```
={"Total Weight";MAP(D2:D,E2:E,LAMBDA(type,wt,IF(wt="","", IFERROR (SORTN(Round!E2:E,1,,BYROW(INDEX(Round!F2:AE,,XMATCH(type,Round!G1:1)),LAMBDA(d,ABS(wt-d))),1),JOIN("x",SORTN(Square!D2:E,1,,BYROW(INDEX(Square!G2:AA,,XMATCH(type,Square!G1:1)),LAMBDA(d,ABS(wt-d))),1))))))}
```

This formula was built to find the value of particular cell, then find the closest value in a table. I'm unable to repurpose it for the following desired outcome. I tried to get it to match to a different row/col in a variety of manners. I've undone all of my failed attempts and simply put the formula that I started with in G2. It's not even multiplying F2*.

Here's an overview of the use case:

- A person will select a label in ColD. This data validation is a combination of all the "styles" found on Round & Square tabs. Each item is unique to one sheet or the other.
- A person will select a size value in ColE. This data validation is a combination of all the possible sizes found on the Round & Square tabs. Because there is no dependency in place, a person could select a style from the round sheet and a size from the square sheet. This isn't ideal, but also not really an issue. I am certain I can add an if statement to deliver a "Not Valid" error message in Col G.
- A person will enter a quantity in ColF. This is just a regular field.
- ColG will then look through Round to see if the style listed in ColD exists. If not, it will find it in Square.
- Regardless of what sheet the formula has identified, the next step is to have ColG look for the value in ColD in the 1st row of the target sheet. Then find the value in that column that corresponds to the row which will be matched from the value in ColE of the Pizza tab.

Below are samples from the square and round tabs. The data generated in these parts of the spreadsheets are dynamically generated using formulas/data from the first handful of columns of said sheet.

Sample from Square Tab:
[image: Portion of the Square Tab]

Sample from Round Tab:
[image: Portion of the Round Tab]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Added formula to your [sheet here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1q9Jco4RXpSqmxyezycUHwsmq7c5eRra5swRnzOILQlQ/edit#gid=2069324283&range=G2):

```
=map(D2:D,E2:E,F2:F,lambda(d,e,f,
                if(len(d)*len(e)*len(f),f*
                max(iferror(filter(filter(Square!G2:J,Square!G1:J1=d),Square!F2:F=e)),
                    iferror(filter(filter(Round!F2:O,Round!F1:O1=d),Round!E2:E=e))),)))
```

[image]

Comment: spectacular. thank you so very much.